# Implement Fingerprint login in react native application

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb, react-native

I am creating an application in `react native`. With react native, I am using `nodejs` and `mongodb` at my backend. With login form, I also have to give user option to login via fingerprint.

I am new to react native and nodejs. So my concern is below:

> 1) How can i implement fingerprint login in reactnative.
>
> 2) Do i need to do anything at my backend(nodejs) to login via fingerprint.

Answer (score 1):

1) You can use the following library [react-native-fingerprint-scanner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fingerprint-scanner)

2) For your backend you would need to do the saving or handling of the logic for something like sessions or the normal login.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, What i will got from frontend to save in db?

Comment: im not sure. If im reading the api right i dont think you get any value back rather then if it worked or not. But you would need to tell the user by theyre fingerprint im not sure how to do it. I could image something like showing a dialog once after the fingerprint was successful where the user needs to enter his password. This way you can at least be sure that the fingerprint is from a person knowing the password